# How to change the image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const image_click = document.querySelectorAll('.imgClickBtn');
for (let image_clickBtn of image_click) {
  image_clickBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let parent = image_clickBtn.parentElement;
    let file = parent.querySelector('.updateprofile');
    let filevalue = "";
    file.click();
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
      var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
      filevalue = fileName;
    });
    image_clickBtn.src = "assets/Blog-post/" + filevalue;
  })
}
```

Comment: so what's your question? and are you going to use jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: Looks like both javascript and jQuery.  However, some comments about what this code is supposed to do would be helpful.  I looks like it is supposed to take a input file's value and change the clickButton's src value to that file.

Comment: Dude don't leave a guessing game like this. Form a proper question to receive adequate help.

Comment: Jason, if I'm right about you're  wanting to display an uploaded image when your image_clickBtn is clicked, then you're going to have to upload the file, possibly using ajax and a form variable, to the  server when the input file's value is changed so that it is available in your assets/Blog-post directory when the button is clicked.

Comment: precisely i cant change the image the filevalue always been null

Answer (score 0):

```
let imgdisplay;
const ImgBtnX = document.querySelectorAll('.ImgBtnX');
                for (let ImgBtnX1 of ImgBtnX) {
                    ImgBtnX1.addEventListener("click",function () {
                        let parent = ImgBtnX1.parentElement;
                        let file = parent.querySelector('.Update_Post');
                        file.click();
                       window.imgdisplay = parent.querySelector('.Image_Blog');
                    })
                }

          function readURL(input) {
          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
            window.imgdisplay.src =  e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
          }
        }
   $('.Update_Post').change(function(e) {
         readURL(this)

    });
```

I've already solve my problem using this codes